# Groovy TupleConstructor weirdness with Eclipse

Tags: groovy, eclipse-neon

I have the three following classes that all form an inheritance hierarchy with each other:

```
@Canonical
class Widget {
    String author
}

@Canonical
@TupleConstructor(includeSuperProperties = true, callSuper = true)
class FileWidget extends Widget {
    File file
}

interface HasImage {
    BufferedImage getImage()
}

@Canonical
@TupleConstructor(includeSuperProperties = true, callSuper = true)
class ImageFileWidget extends FileWidget implements HasImage {
    Boolean hasColor
    BufferedImage image
}
```

Now I am likely using `@Canonical` and/or `@TupleConstructor` incorrectly, but the desired behavior here is the **requirement** to instantiate an `ImageFileWidget` using all of its properties as well as those of its parent objects. So something like:

```
class Driver {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        String author = 'me'
        File file = new File('some/path')
        Boolean hasColor = true
        BufferedImage image = null

        ImageFileWidget imageFileWidget = new ImageFileWidget(author, file, hasColor, image)
    }
}
```

But when I run this from inside Eclipse I get:

```
Caught: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: com.me.myapp.ImageFileWidget(java.lang.String, java.io.File, java.lang.Boolean, null)
```

groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: com.me.myapp.ImageFileWidget(java.lang.String, java.io.File, java.lang.Boolean, null)
        at com.me.myapp.Driver.main(Driver.groovy:10)

Furthermore, when I print out `ImageFileWidget.constructors` like so:

```
printn ImageFileWidget.constructors
```

I get:

```
[
    public com.me.myapp.ImageFileWidget(),
    public com.me.myapp.ImageFileWidget(java.lang.Boolean),
    public com.me.myapp.ImageFileWidget(java.lang.Boolean,java.awt.image.BufferedImage)
]
```

...But, when I run it from inside Gradle (via Application plugin) everything works perfectly (I get the right constructors generated for me, and no exception gets thrown)...

So it seems that Groovy is not honoring my `includeSuperProperties` argument to `@TupleConstructor`, or something similar. Any ideas where I'm going awry here?

Comment: Why do you need canonical?

Comment: I tried your example and it worked... I wonder why. Which version are you using?

Comment: Thanks @tim_yates (+1) - if possible I'd like a nice `toString()` as well as `hashCode`/`equals` for use with `HashSets`. But this is not a strict requirement. Your question is certainly interesting though! Either you suspect that I don't know what `@Canonical` is, in which case its a tad bit  condescending (!), or you're implying that my use of it is somehow interfering w/ my use of `@TupleConstructor`!

Comment: And I'm using Groovy 2.4.7 @WillP (+1).

Comment: Hmmm interesting...I've been running this from inside Eclipse. Just ran it via Gradle and, yes, it works correctly. Damn you Eclipse!!! I'll leave this question open and change it to reflect it as an Eclipse problem, and see if anyone addresses it...